# find my iPhone is 'offline'

Tags: icloud

I lost my iPhone after I checked it in find my phone it shows that the device is offline.

I want to know it means that the phone is 100% switched off or find my iPhone was not kept on in my iPhone [because I don't remeber correctly it was on or not]

Does find my iPhone works on International Mobile Equipment identity number or Subscriber Identity Module?

Answer (score 1):

You can not find out if the phone is 100% turned off.  The issue is that the phone may not have any network connectivity which would cause it to show as off line in find my phone.

The phone needs to communicate with Apple's servers and let them know that it is on and the GPS provides the location information.  If a person were to keep the phone on, but turn on Airplane mode, then the phone will show as offline in find my phone.

Sorry about you losing your phone...hope this answers your question.

Comment: ok thank you for that. actually my phone already has a pass code, now how can the thief make the device online as he cannot cross the lock screen. Also if he inserts another Subscriber Identity Module network to that iPhone whether then also find my iPhone application will find it? What are the possibilities of finding my phone

Comment: Depending on which version of iOS you have, the thief can't get past the pass code so if they turn it on they would be stuck.  Now they can still place the phone in a mode called DFU recovery which would disable all services and allow them to connect the phone to iTunes and do a complete restore or wipe.  Changing the SIM card won't do anything other then give the phone a new number, but you would still be able to see if it came back online.  At this point, I would just call your cell phone carrier and let them know the IMEI of your phone and tell them it was stolen. Can't really get it back.

Comment: Did this resolve your question?  If so, can I get a +1 on the answer?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but just for the sake of other users, personally I would check Find My iPhone on iCloud or with the app ASAP. If it is offline, check the option to enable Lost Mode, if the phone comes back online your message and number will be displayed on the lock screen. Also I would NOT alert my carrier of the stolen phone for maybe a few days or weeks as once you mark the phone as stolen, the carrier will disable all communication services on the phone effectively killing Find My iPhone and your chances of getting your phone back.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the question about whether the phone is on or not, it is either **on (but has no internet connection)**, **or is completely dead/switched off**.

Find My iPhone is **certainly** on because if you didn't switch it on, or if it was turned off after setup of the device, it would not appear at all in the Find My iPhone app or on iCloud.

Find My iPhone **does not** run on SIM cards nor does it run on IMEIs, it solely works based on Apple iCloud Servers.